# RAM usage 99% when trying to generate csv for a million records Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, ubuntu, ram

I have these two tables installations and clients.
installations has around a million records, with around 400k clients

```
class Installation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :client, optional: true
end
```

and

```
class Client < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :installations
end
```

I need to generate a csv in which there will be million installations records including username and link_to_profile of related client (if present)

code to generate csv is

```
  require 'csv'
  def self.generate_csv
    attributes = %w{ app_identifier app_name device_type  installation_id app_version time_zone created_date updated_date username link_to_profile }

      CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
      csv << attributes

      Installation.all.each do |installation|
        data = [installation.app_identifier, installation.app_name , installation.device_type  , installation.db_id , installation.app_version , installation.time_zone , installation.created_date , installation.updated_date ]
        if installation.client.present?
           data << installation.client.username
           data << installation.client.link_to_profile
        end
        csv << data
      end
    end
  end
```

so with each installation , its respective client (if present) is also loaded to get its username and link_to_profile

I have 8 GB RAM, When I call generate_csv , RAM usage is 20%.
it start increasing and after some time like a Lac records it reaches around 99.7 % and than swap goes to 50% and system hangs, no further processing.

Whats the issue here and how can I solve this?

Comment: Have you checked out [batches](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html)?

Comment: didn't tried them, but eager loading worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try some eager loading:

```
require 'csv'
def self.generate_csv
  attributes = %w{ app_identifier app_name device_type  installation_id app_version time_zone created_date updated_date username link_to_profile }

    CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
    csv << attributes

    Installation.includes(:client).each do |installation|
      data = [installation.app_identifier, installation.app_name , installation.device_type  , installation.db_id , installation.app_version , installation.time_zone , installation.created_date , installation.updated_date ]
      if installation.client
         data << installation.client.username
         data << installation.client.link_to_profile
      end
      csv << data
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: another thing, I searched and tried Installation.find(:all, :include => :clients) but it gives error

Comment: `Installation.includes(:client).` and `if installation.client`

Comment: Experiment by replacing `Installation.includes(:client).each` with `Installation.includes(:client).find_each`.

Comment: If you're actually only interested in Installations that do have a Client, use 'Installation.joins(:client).includes(:client)` for even more efficiency.